# Export excel rows to individual text files

Tags: excel, vba, export, range

I'm using the VBA code below to export Excel rows to individual text file (file name is Column B)

```
Sub ExportTextFiles()

Dim i As Long
Dim LastDataRow As Long
Dim MyFile As String
Dim fnum

LastDataRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To LastDataRow
    'The next line uses the contents of column B on the same row to name it
    MyFile = "C:\test\" & ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value & ".txt"
    fnum = FreeFile()
    Open MyFile For Output As fnum

    Print #fnum, Format(Range("A" & i))
    Close fnum
Next i
End Sub
```

My problem is only 255 Characters of row exported in the text. 
is there a workaround ?

Comment: Lose the `Format` function in your `Print` statement

Answer (score 1):

For reasons that I have not been able to find clear documentation, when you use the `Format` function with no format defined, it will return only 255 characters.

I don't understand why you need to use the `Format` function in your `Print` statement, but if you remove it, the 255 character limitation seems to disappear.

The only thing I think you might have to worry about is the cell contents limitation of 32,767 characters.